# Ruby on Rails put app folder into separate feature subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to go from the following structure in my Rails app:

```
app /
 models /
    model_a
    model_b
    ...
 controllers /
    controller_a
    controller_b
    ...
```

to (same repo)

```
domain1 /
  app /
    models /
      model_a
    controllers/
      controller_a

domain2 /
  app /
     models /
       model_b
     controllers / 
       controller_b
```

This is so that I can have some logical isolation in a big app.  Domain 1 would have no direct dependency to domain 2 except through API's.  When I change stuff in domain1, I only want to run all the specs in the domain1 folder.  When the app is run and deploy, it will still load the code under all the domains.  What do I have to do to make such a folder structure change, and can I avoid having to re-namespace all my files?